# Regex for finding "real" 3-digit sequences (ignoring those embedded in 4-digit sequences)

Tags: regex

I'd like a regex (using Java) that captures three digits such as "876", but not if they are buried inside a 4-digit sequence.

To capture "876" within "876" and "foo876" and "  876 " and "876" and "food876" and "4foo876".

But NOT  within "88foo9876" or "9876" or "a8876" or "a8876foo".

How do I do this?

I want to say something like   *X(\d\d\d)X*, but in place of the first X in that to say "*\D* or *^* (start-string)" and in place of the second X in that to say "*\D* or *$* (end-string)".

Edit:

For answers, see Xanatos, also Code Jockey, and Tim Pietzcker.

Comment: More examples of passess and failures will help.  I'm a little confused.

Comment: You should always specify the language you are using the Regex from. It's written even in the description of the regex tag.

Comment: How do feel about `apple 3.14159 with cheddar`?  What about `1a2b3c`?

Comment: How about the test cases @AlanMoore provided: Should it match `1foo876bar2` or `876foo876`?

Comment: Not match "apple 3.14159 with cheddar" or "1a2b3c".

Comment: Match "1foo876bar2" and (twice) "876foo876" –

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well, then! for X(\d\d\d)X as you asked for, use

```
(?<=\D|^)(\d\d\d)(?=\D|$)
```

which is

```
(?<=\D|^)      # lookbehind for «\D or ^ (start-string)»
(\d\d\d)       # then match «three digits such as "876"»
(?=\D|$)       # lookahead for «\D or $ (end-string)»
```

and will

> ...capture "876" within "876" and "foo876" and " 876 " and "876" and "food876".
>
> But NOT within "88foo9876" or "9876" or "a8876" or "a8876foo".

as you specified :D

Here it is shown below in RegexBuddy:

[image: Screenshot of RegexBuddy showing .Net regex emulation]

if you're using a language without lookbehind (like ECMA/JavaScript) you'll have to either use

```
(\D|^)(\d\d\d)(?=\D|$)     # and use the second capturing group -or-
                           # use
(?:\D|^)(\d\d\d)(?=\D|$)   # and use the first capturing group
```

Comment: +1 for the proper explanation. I am curious though, is there any reason to use a lookahead instead of a normal group or non-capturing group? (regardless of language it is used in\) and uuuh \d{3} seems like a slightly smarter way to match 3 digits

Comment: Yup. Looks like just what the OP ordered. +1

Comment: @sg3s: You're right, the lookarounds aren't really pulling their weight.  Note, however, that `(?:\D|^)(\d\d\d)(?:\D|$)` will consume the leading and trailing non-digit characters if they're present.  If you needed the regex to consume *only* the three digits (for example, if you were unable to use the capturing group to retrieve them), then you would need the lookarounds.

Comment: Some languages don't allow for variable-length lookbehinds. In that case (and also to perhaps make the regex more readable), you could use `(?<!\d)\d\d\d(?!\d)` with the same result.

Comment: Thanks, that works! I tested it with  String[] matches = { "876", "foo876", " 876 ", "876", "food876", "4foo876" };
String[] notHere = { "88foo9876", "9876", "a8876", "a8876foo" };

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: Updated according to clarified specs:

```
(?<!\d)\d{3}(?!\d)
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!\d) # Assert that there is no digit before the current position
\d{3}   # Match exactly three digits
(?!\d)  # Assert that there is no digit after the current position
```

---

(initial version preserved for archival purposes :))

```
^\D*\d{3}$
```

if I understand you correctly.

**Explanation:**

```
^     # start of string
\D*   # zero or more non-digits
\d{3} # exactly 3 digits
$     # end of string
```

Comment: Thanks for that regex. I have clarified the "passes" and "fails" some more in my question. Basically, I want to find 3-digit sequences, but only "real" 3-digit sequences. If they are embedded in 4-digit sequences, I don't want them.

Comment: `^\D*\d{3}\D*$` works correctly for all the test cases provided so far, but it wouldn't match "1foo876bar2" or "876foo876".

Comment: Sorry, I guess that clarifying the spec is half the challenge. I would like to match "1foo876bar2".

Comment: @Joshua Fox: The new version matches all these (it matches twice in `876foo876`).

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<!\d)(\d{3})(?!\d)
```

Test here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2utct

Using zero width capturing groups. Means 3 digits not preceeded by a digit and not followed by a digit. The only thing captured is the 3 digits.

Note that if you are using .NET, instead of `\d` you should use [0-9] to not capture things like 09E6 ০ BENGALI DIGIT ZERO (the ০ is your digit :-) )

Comment: Thanks for that regex. I have clarified the "passes" and "fails" some more in my question. Basically, I want to find 3-digit sequences, but only "real" 3-digit sequences. If they are embedded in 4-digit sequences, I don't want them.

Comment: +1. This new, lookaround-based version meets the revised requirements, but of course, it requires support for both lookahead and lookbehind, and the OP still hasn't said what flavor he's using.

Answer (score 2):

```
^\D*\d{3}$
```

The above works but your requirements are a little vague. Non digit means literally non digits so everything else is allowed even spaces.

Comment: You're right,  my requirements were vague.  I guess that clarifying the spec is half the challenge. In brief, I want to capture any sequence of three digits as long as it is not embedded in a longer digit sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I’m assuming that what you actually want is a regexp that matches legal variable names as defined by many programming languages.  Let’s say you’re after strings with at least one non-digit at the beginning, then anything: that would be `/^\D+.*/` (your mileage may vary, depending on the programming language).  Of course, if I’m right in my assumption, `\D` is actually not at all what you want at the beginning; you’d rather want a list of characters that can legally start a variable (roughly, alphabetical character, plus the underscore, and possibly a few other characters).  Hence that would be more like `/[A-Za-z_]+.*/`

But you really need to be more specific, as has already been said.

Answer (score 0):

This is a regex that will match a sequence of 3 digits not immediatly preceded or succeeded by another digit.

```
[^\d](\d{3})[^\d]/
```

The caret (^) negates the character class which means it matches anything except digits. the {3} specifies how many digits need to be in the digit sequence in the middle.

Edit, sorry I didn't test it on single strings in which the sequence starts and/or ends with a digit in a sequence we want.. This should fix that, <s>gets a few extra captures, but you can ignore those.</s> Fixed that too since I'm too much of a perfectionist

```
(?:^|[^\d])(\d{3})(?:[^\d]|$)
```

Some more explanation, in parts.

`(?:^|[^\d])` ; the `?:` makes the group (everything, between the () brackets) non-capturing. `^|[^\d]` means either the start of the string, or anything that isn't a digit.

`(\d{3})` ; capture group of exactly 3 digits

`(?:[^\d]|$)` ; basically does the same as the beginning but then with the end of a string or anything that is not a digit...

Comment: There's a shorthand for `[^\d]` (which is used in the revised question): `\D`

Comment: Seems to be a mistake: Searching for "876" on string "foo876" this captures "o876", but it should capture "876". I tested using Java and also here http://www.regextester.com